# Multithreading in WCF

Tags: multithreading, wcf, locking, mutex

I am trying solve this problem. I have WCF service. Client can call web method from this service which only "fire" another method (this method only write data to database) in another thread.

Code is here:

```
    //this method will write data to database
    public void WriteToDb()
    {

    }

    //this web method will call only mehod WriteToDb() in another thread
    public void SomeWebMethod()
    {
        new Task(WriteToDb).Start();

    }
```

Problem is that in same time can web method call 5 clients. This cause that method WriteToDb is called 5 times in 5 thread.

In all 5 cases method WriteToDb will use same data.

My aim is achieve this behavior. 5 clients called web method SomeWebMethod. Method WriteToDb will run in 5 thread.

But I would like execute first thread, then second thread ....etc and on the end 5th thread.

I don’t want run method WriteToDb in same time in 5 thread.

So maybe I can use lock.

```
{
    private object locker = new object();

    //this method will write data to database
    public void WriteToDb()
    {

        lock(locker)
        {
            //write to DB
        }

    }
```

I am not sure because .net assembly is host on app domain a app domain is host on win process. I woud like to avoid deadlocks.

What happens if I have a machine with 6 CPU? Use mutex instead lock ?

Thank you for help...

Answer (score 0):

A lock is fine here, but you should make your `locker` object `static` so the same object instance is used in the lock every time.

It does not matter how many cores you have - if you hold the lock on an object then any other threads that attempt to acquire the lock will wait until the lock is released.

A deadlock can only occur if you are acquiring multiple locks in different orders in different threads.

I suggest you read Joe Albahari's excellent [free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particulary sure what you are writing to DB, but your question is loosely coupled with WCF to be frank, try to read CLR via C# on multithreading etc.

Also regarding WCF, you can setup how your service object is created upon requests, ie per call, per session or singleton, and for later use specify if it's methods will stuck in queue or will be called on object concurrently.

So depending on choosing architecture you can either relay on WCF ability to host single object which will have logic you described or you can go the way tried.

Links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx